# Firefox w/ Mouse dragging

Tags: javascript, firefox, mouse, mouseevent

I am trying to make an iPad like interface and everything is great except for firefox (obviously IE does not work right now).  The mouse fallback (non touch screens) cannot seem to handle more than one mouse drag event.  The screen starts freezing up and it "moves" all the html as if it were an image.

Things that you may want to know:

MacOSX 10.8
FireFox 14.0.1

---

I made an example of a very simple jsfiddle item that seems to do it for me, (as i hope it does for you), and then a working example from hammer.js's website.

http://jsfiddle.net/QD2ew/13/

^-- here is the example of what is going wrong (for me at least).

http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/

^-- Here is a working example

What is going wrong between these 2 code units?

Comment: If you are adding fiddle links, that's great, but Stack Overflow requires to have relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: @Xan They were relevant code links.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Certainly; but the links can go dead, and the question is supposed to be up forever to help others with the same problem. See [ask] for an official position on Fiddle links. Please edit your question and your answer to contain code in question.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/QD2ew/18/

^-- answer.

So what happens is that Firefox will treat an empty div as an image, its mouse events will be taken over almost immediately (2nd drag attempt).

So to fix it, i put a hidden div within the element (visibility:hidden).

Wowza, wat a sucky bug!  Thanks for those who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something with console.log() isn't working right with jsfiddle. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/QD2ew/19/